# Access Feature Classes on Multiple Database Schemas with ArcSDE

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am using ArcObjects to access a GeoDatabase that was set up with ArcSDE 10 and SQL Server 2008 R2.  In this particular case, I have some tables set up on alternate schemas (this is to replicate a clients' environment).

The OpenFeatureClass method on the IFeatureWorkspace is working correctly when I access feature classes that are in the default schema (SDE).

That same method will fail, however, when I try to access feature classes on the other schemas.  The error I'm getting is "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Has anyone had a similar issue?  Is there something I should do to ensure the other feature classes are accessible to ArcObjects?

***UPDATE***

Brad Nesom made a good point in the comments about whether the alternate schema tables are spatial.  The table WERE spatial, but for some reason after I changed the schema, they were changed to non-spatial.  It's possible that ArcSDE does not allow you to modify schemas for spatial tables.

Comment: if the schema is not "registered" with sde, I think you will have to use alternative methods to access through arcobjects.

Comment: @Brad - How do you register the schema?  As far as I know, sdetable -o register will only work with tables.

Comment: I think where I was heading was that maybe an oledb connection or other access method.

Comment: are these tables on the alternte schema spatial?

Comment: @Brad - Yes, the other tables are spatial

Comment: @Brad - I double checked, turns out they were changed to non-spatial when I altered the schema.

Comment: Does this link help? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Installations_of_SQL_Server_and_ArcSDE_on_separate_servers/002q000000m5000000/     take a look at the multiple geodatabase section

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can connect to the geodatabase in arccatalog, you should be able to list the properties in IGxDatabase.WorkspaceName.ConnectionProperties, then use those to devise a method to open the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can work with with non-SDE schemas without any problem, but the only condition is to register it with SDE. In case your schema has been changed from SDE to something else, a post-installation configuration should help you registering the new schema.